# Is is safe to use dictionary class as switch case for python?

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

If my program is looping the Dictionary class for switch case will it cause any memory issue? Correct me if i am wrong, python will populate the whole new dictionary class object when ever i call a dictionary(x) to return value?

EDIT:
I have created a function something like this, with more data inside.

```
def switch(tcpData):
    return{
    'functionA':fnA
    'functionB':fnB
    'functionC':fnC
    }.get((tcpData.split(" "))[0].rstrip(), "Invalid")
```

Below is my simplified tcp server code

```
...
...
    client_sock, address = server.accept()
    print 'Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1])
    connected=True
    while connected:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            connected=False
        if "\r" in data:
            print switch(data)
            conn.sendall(switch(data)+"\n\r")
...
...
```

**As I mentioned earlier, python will populate the whole new dictionary class object whenever i call the switch function**.
Lets say my switch dictionary contains a lot of data and I am receiving tcp data at the rate of 10Hz or 20Hz , will it consume all the RAM memory after sometime?

Comment: You should probably show some code so we know what you are doing.

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the dictionary will be re-created if you leave and then re-enter that scope, for example

```
def switch(a):
    responses = {1: 'a',
                 2: 'b',
                 3: 'c'}
    print(id(responses))
    return responses[a]
```

Notice that the `id` of `responses` keeps changing which illustrates that a new object has been created each time

```
>>> switch(1)
56143240
'a'
>>> switch(2)
56143112
'b'
>>> switch(3)
56554184
'c'
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying this for me! So will it consume up my RAM memory if i keep on looping it? Please see my edited question, i have added in more detail about it.

Comment: @anoobprogrammer No it will not consume more and more memory. Python has a garbage collector that will reuse the memory of objects as they fall out of scope and aren't referenced any more. So while you'll have a hit in efficiency, you will not be accumulating memory.

Comment: I have tried today the same code from @CoryKramer 's answer in Python 3.7.4. Using IPython I get the same change of id, but executing it from a file, I get the same id number in all the calls, meaning that the dictionary does not change if executed from script.